# Multivariable local CLT for uncorrelated (but dependent) coordinates?

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, limit-theorems

Let $\vec f, \vec g\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I_n)$ be independent Gaussians.
Define $\mathsf{cyc}^i(\vec f) = (\vec f_i, \vec f_{i+1},\dots, \vec f_{n-1}, \vec f_0, \vec f_1,\dots, \vec f_{i-1})$ to be the cyclic rotation of $\vec f$ by $i$ coordinates.
Define $\vec h_i = \langle \mathsf{cyc}^i(\vec f), \vec g\rangle$.
For an easier-to-parse explanation, I will note that when $n = 3$ I am defining

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec h_0\\
\vec h_1\\
\vec h_2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\vec f_0\vec g_0 + \vec f_1\vec g_1 + \vec f_2\vec g_2\\
\vec f_1\vec g_0 + \vec f_2\vec g_1 + \vec f_0\vec g_2\\
\vec f_2\vec g_0 + \vec f_0\vec g_1 + \vec f_1\vec g_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am interested in understanding how close $\vec h$ is to a Gaussian.
Ideally, I would hope for a statement of the form

> Let $\vec g'\sim \mathcal{N}(0, n\sigma^4 I_n)$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\frac{\Pr[\vec h = x]}{\Pr[\vec g' = x]} \in[1-\delta_n, 1+\delta_n]$, for error bounds $\delta_n$ that depend only on $n$.

The choice of $n\sigma^4$ is because one can compute $\mathsf{cov}(\vec h) = n\sigma^4 I_n$.
I would expect error bounds $\delta_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^n}$, via analogy with the 1D case (where one gets $\delta_n \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$).

Reasons I hope for such Gaussian approximation are

1. Each $\vec h_i$ individually is close to a 1D gaussian, and
2. The coordinates of $\vec h$ are uncorrelated.

Of course though, $\vec h$ is not itself written as a summation of independent random variables, so ignoring the dependence (as I clearly want to do) may be unjustified.